# Imposible usar el emulador de Android Studio en un equipo Mac después de casi 20 minutos de tediosa espera

Tags: android-studio, macos

Intento usar el emulador de Android Studio en un equipo Mac y no funciona:

- El ventilador se pone a 1000 x hora
- El equipo se pone lento
- Para compilar tarda muchísimo tiempo (no es problema de la App, si pruebo con un móvil conectado por USB lo hace rápido)
- Al cabo de un rato aparece la pantalla del dispositivo del emulador
- Sigue compilando ... ... ...
- Y luego da error:

> Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Missing initial data partition file:
>   /Users/yo/.android/avd/Nexus_6_API_25.avd/userdata.img

Y también otro error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- A todo eso, sigue compilando: *Gradle build runing ...* Y al cabo de unos 10 minutos termina con una compilación sin errores. Y el ventilador a toda marcha
- La pantalla del dispositivo del emulador da indicios de que se está encendiendo
- De ahí no pasa. Ventilador a tope y máquina super lenta.

**¿Es tan tedioso usar el emulador en Mac OS X?**

**¿Conocen alguna manera de poder usarlo y que no sacrifique los recursos de mi equipo?**

Esta es la secuencia de mensajes de error:

> 19:38 Emulator: WARNING: HAXM 6.0.3 is installed. Please install HAXM
>
> > = 6.2.1 to fix compatibility issues on Mac.
>
> 19:38 Emulator: Warning: requested RAM 1536M too high for your system.
>   Reducing to maximum supported size 1024M
>
> 19:38 Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Missing initial data partition file:
>   /Users/yo/.android/avd/Nexus_6_API_25.avd/userdata.img
>
> 19:48 Gradle build finished in 10m 3s 454ms
>
> 19:55 Emulator: emulator: ERROR: detected a hanging thread 'QEMU2 main
>   loop'. No response for 15008 ms

Al final el emulador se queda bloqueado y tengo que forzar la salida. El ventilador sigue a tope a las 20:00 horas.

---

#### EDICIÓN

Actualicé Android Studio e instalé la última versión `HAXM`. Ahora todo es peor, el equipo se reinicia cuando intento usar el emulador.

La configuración de mi equipo es esta:

> ```
>   Nombre del modelo:  MacBook Air (finales de 2010)
>   Identificador del modelo:   MacBookAir3,2
>   Nombre del procesador:  Intel Core 2 Duo
>   Velocidad del procesador:   1,86 GHz
>   Cantidad de procesadores:   1
>   Cantidad total de núcleos:  2
>   Caché de nivel 2:   6 MB
>   Memoria:    4 GB
>   Velocidad del bus:  1,07 GHz
>   Sistema operativo: OS X Sierra 10.12.6
> ```

Comment: Me pasa lo mismo, y se devora la batería. En Mac pruebo con dispositivo real.

Comment: Yo uso una mac, no tengo problema en usar el emulador, me parece que en tu caso tenes muy poca ram, por eso se generan fallos de pagina y no logra cargar nunca el emulador, tene en cuenta que el emulador consume muchos recursos porque es una maquina virtual

Comment: ¿ Instalaste "Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM Installer)" ?

Comment: @ErickSilva he puesto al final la configuración de mi equipo. ¿Crees que no sea lo bastante potente para correr el emulador de AS? El emulador de XCode funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Por lo que parece... tu equipo va muy justito pero entra dentro de las especificaciones mínimas requeridas: https://androidstudiofaqs.com/conceptos/android-studio-requisitos-minimos A una mala, no lo puedes probar en un dispositivo físico?

Comment: Sí @PabloSimonDiEstefano, de hecho, pruebo la App en un dispositivo físico (móvil), pero quería probarla en una Tablet, y al no tener intenté usar el emulador.

Comment: Me comenta una compañera que ha trabajado en apple que ya es un logro que en ese pc te corra Sierra. XCode te va bien porque las nativas las corre mejor. Por lo visto, está difícil que lo logres.

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano pues Sierra me va de maravilla en este modelo, ningún problema y llevo más de un año con él instalado.

Comment: Si, por eso te digo que es raro. Ese pc te debería de haber actualizado hasta la versión 10.10.x, pero vamos, mejor para tí pero vamos... por lo que parece, ese pc ya no te va a dar de sí para poder utilizar el emulador...

Comment: @A.Cedano el de iOS es un simulador y necesita menos recursos porque comparte los del sistema operativo a diferencia de un emulador que es una maquina virtual y tiene que reservar los recursos del dispositivo que esta emulando

Answer (score 0):

Debes tener instalado

"Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM Installer)"

y en tu emulador cambiar la configuración para emulación de gráficos por software:

`Emulated Performance` > `Graphics` , seleccionar `Software`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Jorge instalé `HAXM`, de hecho me lo sugirió Android Studio cuando hice la última actualización. Puse también la configuración que sugieres. Pero desde que instalé `HAXM` todo es peor: el equipo se reinicia cuando trato de usar el emulador. Puse también la opción que comentas como estaba al principio: `Automatic` y lo mismo, se reinicia el equipo. No hay posibilidad ahora ni siquiera de intentar usar el emulador.